# Menu overflow button on ActionBar/ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

This app was designed before the deprecation of the hardware menu button, so now it automatically shows a menu overflow button at the bottom of our app. We'd rather it wedge itself to the right of our 4 tab bar items when needed.

If that's not doable, we'd at least like to be able to center the lonely menu overflow button like it appears on the first pic here -> http://www.droid-life.com/2012/05/30/dear-developers-can-we-quit-with-the-menu-button-already-and-adopt-an-action-overflow/

We are using ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: Are you using a split action bar? If so, get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

You must add it mannually with setAddOptionMenu(true);

and then create it in xml for example:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/video"
    android:title="@string/video"
    android:icon="@drawable/video"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:title="@string/email"
    android:icon="@drawable/email"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
/>
```

Then inflate it

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.items, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

if you want to split the actionBar in the bottom of the screen you can use

```
android:uiOptions=”splitActionBarWhenNarrow”
```

in your activity in the manifest

hope it helps